# becoming root in terminal? sudo bash vs root#

Tags: bash, terminal, root, sudo, bottle

I'm attempting to install the bottle framework for python from the mac terminal. I'm following a MongoDB University video that says I need to be "root" in order to install the program. However, the video starts at the point where the instructor is already root so it doesn't show how he did it.

The instructors screen shows root# and when he types whoami it shows root. I tried to type sudo root#(which asks me for a password and then says command not found) and root#. Neither one works. When I type sudo bash, I'm able to do whoami root.

Is sudo bash the same as root#?

Comment: `sudo pip install bottle`, then enter your own password when prompted.

Answer (score 3):

There is no command called `root#`, which is why it says "Command not found". There are multiple ways to get an interactive root shell, but `root#` is not one of them.

1. `sudo bash` - type your own password
2. `sudo -i` - type your own password
3. `sudo su` - type your own password
4. `su` - type the root password.
5. `ssh root@localhost` - type the root password.

Note that all the places where I said "type your own password" do not require a password if you have the following line in your `sudoers` file:

```
<my_User_name>   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```